# A specific number which represents Vishnu based on Scriptural sources

Tags: scripture, vishnu, vaishnavism, mathematics, numbers

Is there an abstract numerical number directly representing or connecting with Vishnu as per scripture, please don't say an answer like Dashavatar unless it says the number 10 of the dashavatara represents Vishnu I want something direct and preferably from Vaishnava sources.